# Redirect not working from child function laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a situation where I need to redirect to some route from the child function.

```
function pfunction(){
    $value='a';
    $res = $this->childfunction($value);

    if(count($res)>0){
       //do stuff
    }
}

function childfunction($value){
    if(gettype($value)=='object'){
        //do stuff
    }else{
        return Redirect::route('nextroute');
    }
}
```

now when I run the code It gives the error.

> "count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable".

Comment: im not sure why you're "counting" a redirect anyways

Comment: its not counting the redirect its optional sometime $value will be object but if the $value is not object then redirect to other route

Comment: Does my answer solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

`Redirect::route()` will simply return what the response needs to be.
You can use `abort()` to terminate instantly instead.

`abort(Redirect::route('nextroute'));`

Comment: @mohd-mobeen Is there a reason you unaccepted the answer?